# What is the origin of the idiom "tearing hair out"?

Tags: etymology, british-english

What is the origin of the idiom "tearing hair out" or "pulling my hair out"?

Comment: I wonder if it's just evolved from [trichotillomania](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trichotillomania), which `may be triggered by ... stress.`

Comment: You can tell that this practice was common 1000s of years ago because the Talmud warns against this way of showing excessive mourning: http://jhom.com/topics/hair/mourning.html

Comment: This isn't an "idiom"; it literally refers to hair being torn out in dispair.

Comment: Keep in mind that maybe as recent as 500 years ago most people did not keep their hair cut reasonably short.  Men's hair would often be shoulder length or longer, and of course women's hair would tend to be longer still.  So it was quite possible to grab your hair and pull on it in times of despair or rage, not much different from gritting your teeth or digging your fingernails into your palm.  No doubt, in extreme cases people managed to pull some hair out (just as the tooth gritting or fingernail digging could do some damage).

Comment: @Hot Licks: What do you mean, 500 years ago?  Long hair has been fairly common in western culture since the 1960s.  And while I may not literally pull my hair out, I do tend to run my fingers through it when I'm e.g. working on a frustrating problem.  So the 'idiom' is likely nothing more than a somewhat exaggerated description.

Comment: @jamesqf - In today's Western culture a few men have long hair.  500 years ago pretty much everyone did.  (And long beards, too.)  Short hair was a status symbol of the rich.

Comment: @Hot Licks: Perhaps things are different where you live, but hereabouts (western US), quite a few men (maybe even a majority - I've never counted) have hair long enough to grasp.  Beards aren't uncommon, though most  tend to be trimmed fairly short, but still graspable.

Comment: @jamesqf - "Long enough to grasp" is maybe 3 inches, which is not long.  Long, by modern standards, would be 8-12 inches.  It's not simply a matter of hair being long enough to grasp, it's having it long enough where grasping is commonplace, and could easily occur unconsciously in a fit of rage or whatever.

Answer (score 4):

OED has this pre-dating Shakespeare:

> **m. to tear (†rend) one's hair,** i.e. as a symptom of passionate grief.
>   1548   *Hall's Vnion: Henry IV* f. xiiijv,   This knight..sobbed, wept, and rent his heare.
>   1609   Shakespeare *Troilus & Cressida* iv. iii. 33   Teare my bright haire, & scratch my praised cheekes.

It is something which can actually be witnessed in more demonstrative cultures. Mourners can indeed pull their own hair.

As an indication of **exasperation**, however ("I was pulling my hair out trying to get the copier to work!") there seems to be rather less information — although [Shyam's trichotillomania](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/125138/18696) may well be related.

Comment: @Shyam Oops. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

There is a specific name for the urge to pull out one's hair - [trichotillomania](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trichotillomania). It is a disorder belonging to the obsessive compulsive spectrum and arises due to anxiety and stress, among other reasons. This idiom (and others like *keep one's hair on*) must have originated from this disorder.

Answer (score 1):

It originates in the Bible in the Book of Nehemiah.  The prophet Nehemiah pulled his hair out in response to the desecration of the holy Temple and at the abuse of the Sabbath.